# Template Match and document

Tags: xml, xslt

Can I do something like that to display the value of the node?

```
<!-- plop.xml : -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
      <node1>hello</node1>
</root>

<xsl:template name="my_template" match="document('plop.xml')/root" >
       <xsl:value-of select="node1"/>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:call-template name="my_template"></xsl:call-template>
```

I want to create special template that will only affect one xml.
I work on asp .net 2.0 C# XslCompiledTransform processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do it like that. *(EDIT: In XSLT 1.0 at least, see [@Alejandro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604661/template-match-and-document/4605300#4605300) for a way to do it in XSLT 2.0.)*

An XML node has no concept of the file it had been stored in, since XML does not necessarily correspond to an actual file in the first place. Therefore you can't write a template that only matches nodes in a certain file.

You can declare a parameter,

```
<xsl:param name="fileName" select="''" />
```

fill it from your C# program with a value of your choice, and then make the XSLT program behave differently based on the value of that parameter:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$fileName = 'plop.xml'">
      <!-- do something -->
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <!-- do something else -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You wrote *An XML node has no concept of the file it had been stored* But it has the concept of URI, so it knows its document URI (accessible only in XPath/XSLT 2.0). Also, do remember that patterns in XSLT 1.0 can't have variable/parameter references.

Comment: @Alejandro: ASP.NET 2.0 C# `XslCompiledTransform` can't do XSLT 2.0, though. But it's interesting that you can retrieve the document URI there, I didn't know that (BTW: What will be the URI if the document is an in-memory object only?). You are right with the patterns, I've removed the wrong examples.

Comment: You are rigth about your fears: there can be resources without URI

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT/XPath 2.0 you can:

```
<xsl:template match="/root[document-uri(.) eq resolve-uri('plop.xml',.)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="node1"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What directory will `resolve-uri()` work against? The current directory of environment, I guess?

Comment: @Tomalak: Good point. I've used `resolve-uri` just to show that `'plop.xml'` is not a full URI. I think one could use the p/2 form for this case.